# Style KendoUI controls to look like standard controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, kendo-ui

We're doing an in-place migration of a fairly large web app (~150 pages, ~150 user controls) from WebForms to MVC.  We've selected KendoUI (MVC Complete) for the MVC control library.

In order to keep the look and feel the same as the existing WebForms pages and controls, we will only be using KendoUI for the Grid, Tree, and Upload controls until such time as we have fully migrated all pages over to MVC.  Note that I recognize the Kendo Grid, Tree, & Upload will be a change in the L&F - that's as much of a change as I could get the biz to agree to :)

Is there a way to style the KendoUI controls to look like standard controls (e.g. standard `<select>`) until such time that we can flip the switch and drop the last reference to the WebForms stuff?

I'd still like to be able to use KendoUI for all controls if possible, but just have them styled "old school" for now.  This way, I can use cascading updates, Kendo Validation, etc.

The controls I'm specifically thinking of are the DropDownList (`<select>`), IntegerTextBox (filtered text input), & ListView (`<select>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've just created our own CSS to override the standard kendo stuff and it's looking pretty good, but would still love to find something OOTB from Telerik.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box theme which mimics the "default" browser theme. The available themes can be seen in our online demos: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid

You can also use the [Theme Builder](http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html) to create a custom theme.